# Get pool name and stash account from nomination pool creator

Tags: polkadot-js, account, mempool

Can you explain me how I retrieve (from Polkadot JS) :

1. The nomination pool name (from a given pool Id)
2. The stash account of nomination pool creator ?

For example, here is the first nomination pool :
https://polkadot.subscan.io/nomination_pool/1

[image]
How can I get the name : Paradox | ParaNodes.io - Nominating hight return ...

And from given creator account address : 12NRTphLWqYK5Tri7V2aVGcXWuJ78NFPPjwSN9ZkUxLhCa78, how do I retrieve 13UVJyLnbVp8c4FQeiGUYwmthuauL7RecwzpKCd3cwgRPCPp address ?

Thanks a lot for you help :)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

To get the name you have to query the metadata:

```
const metadata = await api.query.nominationPools.metadata(pool_id);
```

The result is an hex value: `0x50617261646f78207c20506172614e6f6465732e696f20f09f9a80202d204e6f6d696e6174696e6720686967682072657475726e2c20747275737465642c20696e646570656e64656e742076616c696461746f72732e`

You can convert it to String using the utils from the polkadotJS library:

```
const { hexToString } = require('@polkadot/util');
hexToString(metadata.toHuman()
```

This will return you the name: `Paradox | ParaNodes.io  - Nominating high return, trusted, independent validators.`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't realized the metadata utility :)