# how to fetch list of all nomination pools using polkadot js API

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

fetch list of all nomination pools using polkadot js API. details like poolID, address etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `api.query.nominationPools.poolMembers` [image]

[polkadot js doc](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/polkadot/storage#poolmembersaccountid32-optionpalletnominationpoolspoolmember)

However, we don't need to pass `AccountId32` as it asking to specify parameters. Instead we can retrieve a list of all the keys and entries for the map, refer [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries).

```
const pools = await api.query.nominationPools.poolMembers.entries()
pools.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value.isSome) {
        const poolMemberData = value.unwrap().toHuman();
        console.log('Pool ID:', poolMemberData.poolId);
        console.log(
            'Account ID:', key.args[0].toString(),
            'Pool Member Info:', JSON.stringify(poolMemberData)
            );
        }
    })
```

Also refer this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/using-polkadot-js-api-how-can-we-list-the-members-of-a-kusama-nomination-pool/4257#4257)

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the poolID, you can also query the metadata:

```js
await api.query.nominationPools.metadata(pool_id);
```

You can look more information about this here: [Get pool name and stash account from nomination pool creator](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6954/get-pool-name-and-stash-account-from-nomination-pool-creator)